# Query function to contain date operations [DATE + X number of months]

Tags: date, google-sheets, sum, match, google-query-language

I am querying a Google spreadsheet, using a relatively simple expression:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:J200, "Select A, J", 1)
```

This query produces list of *Offices* and *Last N date* in columns **L** and **M** - see picture below.

What I do next is

1. add 6 months to each of the Last N dates;

```
=IF(M2="","",DATE(YEAR(M2)+0,MONTH(M2)+6,DAY(M2)+0))
```

2. See if any of the resultant dates are equal to or greater than `TODAY()`;
3. If YES, place "ALARM" into column **O** which is then used as a marker elsewhere, by filtering the rows with this value as an identifier.

```
=IF(today()>=X2,"ALARM","")
```

I was wondering if it is possible to create a query where 6 months would already be added to values in Column J and, possibly, the resultant list filtered IF value[i] in column J is greater than or equal to `TODAY()`. By achiving this, the column J would contain only `Last N dates + 6 months` AND `>= TODAY()`;
All examples I have checked seems to operate with dates as filters.

[image]

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NCHy62QVLgcKs8C-YdXdhS6CfRUAnTmyLc20ybuQFaE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 Sheet $Db_data

Comment: @player0 Look for column AA

Comment: I guess you wanna keep also non alarm states?

Comment: @player0 actually not, only where ALARM is TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A1:A,
 ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(YEAR(Sheet1!J1:J), MONTH(Sheet1!J1:J)+6, DAY(Sheet1!J1:J)))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,'ALARM' 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and Col2 >=date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  label Col2'ABCD', 'ALARM''alarm'
  format Col2 'dd-mmm-yyyy'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY({FleetStatus!A1:D, ARRAYFORMULA(
 DATE(YEAR(FleetStatus!J1:J), MONTH(FleetStatus!J1:J)+6, DAY(FleetStatus!J1:J)))}, 
 "select Col1,Col5,'ALARM' 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and Col1 !='IVAN GUBKIN' 
    and Col1 !='VYACHESLAV TIKHONOV'
    and Col4 != 'L'
    and Col5 <=date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  label Col5'+6M', 'ALARM''Alarm'
  format Col5 'dd-mmm-yyyy'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you - much apprecaited!

Comment: How do I delete column ALARM, which is created by the QUERY above? 'Select Col1, Col 5, 'ALARM'

Comment: @AlexShevyakov like this:  `=QUERY({FleetStatus!A1:D, ARRAYFORMULA(
 DATE(YEAR(FleetStatus!J1:J), MONTH(FleetStatus!J1:J)+6, DAY(FleetStatus!J1:J)))}, 
 "select Col1,Col5 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and Col1 !='IVAN GUBKIN' 
    and Col1 !='VYACHESLAV TIKHONOV'
    and Col4 != 'L'
    and Col5 <=date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  label Col5'+6M'
  format Col5 'dd-mmm-yyyy'", 1)`

Comment: Thank you and sorry for troubling